# Changing base URL with jQuery partially working

Tags: jquery

This code works great, it just only works on the `link[href]` and nothing else

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
    $("iframe").contents().find("script[src], img[src], link[href], a[href]").each(function(i) {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com/, "http://www.theotherdomain.com");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you try to set the `href` attribute `this.href = ...` but the only element that has `href` is a link. For images and scripts, you have to set the `src` attribute.

Comment: I've done that with `.find("script[src], img[src], link[href], a[href]")`